# mongoose $addToSet is not compatible with mongoDB $addToSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i've stumbled across a weird problem with mongoose $addToSet in patch function,

i am running this code :

```
    const y = await model.updateOne(
        { _id: '61e0327e3889426f21dbbe25' },
        {
            $addToSet: { links: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'] },
        },
    );
```

when looking at the object in the db i see `links: ['a', 'b', test1', 'test2', 'test3' ]` which correspond to $addToSet with $each operator as explained in these docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-an-array

which should of added this array as single element.

i went over mongoose issues and readme and did not find any reference to that behavior.

mongoose version: 6.0.13
mongo 4.2.3

EDIT:

after comment that pointed out where this behavior is decided and some more digging - the above behavior is implemented in :
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/51e758541763b6f14569744ced15cc23ab8b50c6/lib/types/array/ArrayWrapper.js#L82

yet - this is not documented no where - I can't be the first one that encountered that, and I would of expected well used lib such as mongoose to expose that.

Comment: It seems it's not well documented but https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/51e758541763b6f14569744ced15cc23ab8b50c6/lib/types/array/ArrayWrapper.js#L82 may shed some light

Comment: Thank you Alex, during the question i went deeper in the code and found that. yet it is not documented anywhere ! i can't be the first one to encounter that .

Comment: I am sure you are not the first but you could be the last if you contributed back and create a PR in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/tree/master/docs.  I'm afraid it's not the only undocumented thing, but we can make it better one piece at a time.

Comment: i will add that - thanks !